# Unable to install tensorflow-text and unable to import keras_nlp

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I am trying out the Keras-NLP library by using one of the examples provided on the Keras website. I have installed Keras-NLP using the command `pip install keras-nlp` and Tensorflow(version = 2.9.2).

When I run the following,

```
import keras_nlp
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
```

I get the error as follows

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install -q --upgrade keras-nlp tensorflow')
----> 2 import keras_nlp
      3 import tensorflow as tf
      4 from tensorflow import keras

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_nlp/__init__.py:17, in <module>
     15 from keras_nlp import layers
     16 from keras_nlp import metrics
---> 17 from keras_nlp import models
     18 from keras_nlp import tokenizers
     19 from keras_nlp import utils

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_nlp/models/__init__.py:30, in <module>
     26 from keras_nlp.models.distil_bert.distil_bert_tokenizer import (
     27     DistilBertTokenizer,
     28 )
     29 from keras_nlp.models.roberta.roberta_backbone import RobertaBackbone
---> 30 from keras_nlp.models.roberta.roberta_classifier import RobertaClassifier
     31 from keras_nlp.models.roberta.roberta_preprocessor import RobertaPreprocessor
     32 from keras_nlp.models.roberta.roberta_tokenizer import RobertaTokenizer

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_nlp/models/roberta/roberta_classifier.py:22, in <module>
     20 from keras_nlp.models.roberta.roberta_backbone import RobertaBackbone
     21 from keras_nlp.models.roberta.roberta_backbone import roberta_kernel_initializer
---> 22 from keras_nlp.models.roberta.roberta_preprocessor import RobertaPreprocessor
     23 from keras_nlp.models.roberta.roberta_presets import backbone_presets
     24 from keras_nlp.utils.pipeline_model import PipelineModel

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_nlp/models/roberta/roberta_preprocessor.py:20, in <module>
     17 import copy
     19 import tensorflow as tf
---> 20 import tensorflow_text as tf_text
     21 from tensorflow import keras
     23 from keras_nlp.models.roberta.roberta_presets import backbone_presets

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_text'
```

I also tried to install tensorflow-text using the commands `pip install -U tensorflow-text==2.9.2` and `pip install -U tensorflow-text`. Both of these commands give the following error:

**Error from first command**

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text==2.9.2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text==2.9.2
```

**Error from second command**

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text
```

The system I am using is as follows:

MacOS Monterey
Apple M1 Pro chip

Is there any other prerequisite library I should install to make this work? Thank You in advance!

Comment: I see there is no matching version of 2.9.2 in tensorflow-text https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-text/#history

Comment: Hi @KrithickS. Thanks for this. I tried installing tensorflow-text versions 2.11.0 and 2.9.0 and they are giving me the same error.

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/823

Comment: It seems, there is a version mismatch issue. Please install keras_nlp using `!pip install keras-nlp` which will install all the supported packages like tensorflow, keras and tensorflow-text with their compatible version. Let us know if the issue still perists.